# Create line chart using R by reading data from an excel file

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am in need of your help.
I'm trying to generate a line chart in R using data from 2 excel files.
The graph I'm trying to generate is similar to the one shown below

[image: Grafic]

The data presented in this excel image is an example and has more than 1000 lines, but I only need the first 100 of each file
[Excel file example](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArkqrqscNBM6jLMuRUn9Sm5JC5MVFw?e=qsdtPe)

Thanks for your help

[image: excel]

Comment: We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: @neilfws Thanks for your hint I put an example file

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the .xlt file from your public Onedrive account, I first looked at it with my Linux version of LibreOffice to make sure there was something there, then I did this:

```
> library(haven)
> help(pac=haven)  # drats I thought haven did excel, apparently not
> library(readxl)
> help(pac=readxl)   # read some of the help pages to see if an xlt format would be ok
dat <- read_excel("~/Downloads/teste.xlt") # no confirmation that it would be,
     # so experimented
                                                                                                                  
 str(dat)
#----
tibble [1,001 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Tempo: chr [1:1001] "0" "0.1" "0.2" "0.3" ...
 $ Prob : chr [1:1001] "0.0" "0.095188" "0.1813153" "0.2592441" ...

# So success and now to plot with base graphics, of course.

 plot(Tempo~Prob, dat[1:100, ])
 plot(Prob~Tempo, dat[1:100, ])
```

[image]

Oh, wait. You wanted a line with small points. Then do this:

```
png(); plot(Prob~Tempo, dat[seq(1,101, by=5), ], type ="b", cex=0.2, col="green"); dev.off()
```

[image]